# Docker - Reuse docker-compose configurations for different projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a large Docker project with Dockerfiles for `nginx, apache2, varnish, redis` configured and working well after weeks of changes and testing.

I am now at a point where I setup the projects to use docker-compose and override.yml files for easy setup:

*I am trying to use the same docker-compose setup for multiple projects (websites)*

Normal startup (using `docker-compose.yml and optional docker-compose.override.yml`)
`docker-compose up -d`

Custom startup (using specific docker-compose files)
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f custom/docker-compose.website1.yml up -d`

Both these methods starts up fine:
`docker-compose ps`

***Ignore the fact that they are Exit 0 - I stopped them using `docker-compose stop, the containers work fine`***
nginx-proxy          /usr/bin/supervisord   Exit 0
redis-cache          /usr/bin/supervisord   Exit 0
varnish-cache        /usr/bin/supervisord   Exit 0
web-server-apache2   /usr/bin/supervisord   Exit 0

Now I want a **second project (website)** to use the same docker/docker-compose configuration setup:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f anothercustomfolder/docker-compose.website2.yml up -d`

To my surprise docker-compose ***recreated containers** and do not create a new set of containers:*

**See 'current setup' section for how I setup things.**

```
  Creating network "delete-network-frontend" with the default driver
  Recreating nginx-proxy        ... done
  Recreating varnish-cache      ... done
  Recreating web-server         ... done
  Recreating redis-cache        ... done
```

When running `docker-compose ps` in the second setup folder:

**Note the names are not the same as above (this is the second test setup)**

```
         Name                       Command          State                Ports
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  nginx-proxy-delete       /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp,
                                                          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
  redis-cache-delete       /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp
  varnish-cache-delete     /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:6081->6081/tcp,
                                                          0.0.0.0:6082->6082/tcp
  web-server-              /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
  apache2-delete
```

It appears docker-compose did two things : 1. Recreate (replace) the project 1 containers, used the project 1 container names to mention that they were 'recreated', and 2. Remove the project 1 containers, renamed it to project 2 containers.

## Current setup

- I created a full Dockerfile project configured with docker-compose.yml and two override docker-compose files (`docker-compose.website1.yml and` docker-compose.website2.yml`).
- I made a **complete copy of the working Dockerfile / docker-compose.yml project** and created a new folder:  In other words both these will use the *same docker setup but use different docker-compose.yml override files*.
  `/var/www/docker/site1`
  `/var/www/docker/site2`

### Question

TLDR: How do I use a working `docker-compose` project on the same host operating system for multiple projects... without it replacing another project's containers.

I want to be able to see (use both) at the same time, and for instance be able to see this:
*Ignore the fact that the ports are the same here, I am aware they won't run at the same time, I will update the project docker-compose.yml custom files when this works*

`docker-compose ps`

```
               Name                       Command          State                Ports
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  nginx-proxy              /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp,
                                                          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
  redis-cache              /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp
  varnish-cache            /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:6081->6081/tcp,
                                                          0.0.0.0:6082->6082/tcp
  web-server-              /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
  apache2
  nginx-proxy              /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp,
                                                          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
  redis-cache-delete       /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp
  varnish-cache-delete     /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:6081->6081/tcp,
                                                          0.0.0.0:6082->6082/tcp
  web-server-              /usr/bin/supervisord   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
  apache2-delete
```

### If anyone asks: Why not just put the websites into the same (one) container??

For the possibility someone might ask this, I know I can add multiple websites into the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` (or nginx) and add custom configuration files using `ADD` in Dockerfile for each site, but using that method I *cannot test different slight setups*.

*Different setups that can be used by referencing another different image in the 'override docker-compose files'*

For instance I can create a Dockerfile that installs *all php7.3 libraries required and run Magento 2.3 on it*, then have another Dockerfile to *test php7.4, and have another to run an older Magento 1 site on a PHP5.6 installation and so on*.

Comment: Just want to find out if anyone has advice on using multiple project with the same docker-compose project configuration

Comment: Are you running this all from the same directory?  Are you setting the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variables?  Are you overriding `container_name:` in the `docker-compose.yml` files?

Comment: I'm running it from two different folders, I think.  

Will have a look at `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`, not sure about that - to build I would use `docker-compose build --no-cache --build-arg ARG_I_NEED=val`
and for creating containers: (with overridden values) `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.overrides/docker-override-webserver1.yml up -d`

Comment: Referring to the other answer you just assisted with regarding `container_name`, yes I do: [This docker question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411403/access-container-name-in-dockerfile-from-docker-compose)

Comment: I will test `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` once my images can build correctly again (busy updating based on your answer in other question).
I assume I use `-p` like this `docker-compose up -p PROJECTNAME` in conjunction with other flags?

Comment: Yes, `docker-compose -p` and `$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` do the same thing.  You need to remember to give that `-p` option to _every_ `docker-compose` command.

Comment: I will test on Monday most likely, Dockerfiles need to be fixed still.  Do you mean I need `-p` even on `docker-compose build` too?  Thanks!

Comment: Update on using `-p` flag: `docker-compose -p magento2overridenproject -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.overrides/docker-compose.glo.magento2.3.5.yml up -d`.   When I stop the containers (since I need them to be persistent!) and trying to start again : `docker-compose start`   : I get an error immediately.   `docker-compose start` - `Error: No containers to start`.

Comment: Search in `/var/lib/containers/*` :   I get these entries inside the JSON : `"com.docker.compose.project":"magento2overridenproject"`.  
It attached it, but how can I now use docker-compose to start them again?

Comment: `-p` Absolutely useless by itself, I see I still need to rename the folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to advice from **David Maze**, I struggled further with configuring the docker-compose setup to work with multiple projects.

**Information based on docker-compose v1.25.0 (July 2020)**

*This discussion is especially important when you want to re-use (persist) your containers (start/stop instead of just up/down - deleting)*

As initially pointed out in my question - if you try to create containers using `docker-compose up -d` there are some pitfalls which the tool simply does not support right at the moment.

### Pitfalls

**PITFALLS OF CURRENT DOCKER-COMPOSE IMPLEMENTATION:**

1. If you just use overridden `docker-compose*.yml` with *different container_names (per 'project')* with files in the ***same folder***

> `docker-compose up` will simply **replace existing containers as explained in my question.**

2. You can do the following: `docker-compose -p CUSTOM_PROJECT_NAME -f file1.yml -f file2.yml up -d`, but:

> **This on its own is useless - these containers will only work until you want stop them.**  *As soon as you want to do `docker-compose start` (to restart existing container set)* it will simply fail with **`Error: No containers to start`**

3. If you use two different folders *with the same docker-compose project (ie cloned project):* for instance `./dc-project1` `./dc-project2` but using `container_name` field inside `docker-compose.*.yml file`:

> **When you try to run `docker-compose -f f1.yml -f f2.yml up -d`** inside `./dc-project1` and the same inside `./dc-project2` folder, you will get the following error: `You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name`.

4. Similar issues with your **Docker network will occur with docker-compose when you use overridden files:**
   *Removed most of the custom settings to make the network setting clearer*:

> Network will be attached correctly from your overridden file on `docker-compose up`, **but as soon as you want to `docker-compose start`** it looks for your *default network name:*  in the default `docker-compose.yml` or even the `docker-compose.override.yml` file if it exists. In other words - it ignores your custom docker-compose override files (see example below):

**`docker-compose.yml`:**

```
   networks:
      network_frontend:
          name: stage6-network-frontend
```

**`customfolder/docker-compose.custom.yml`:**

```
   networks:
      network_frontend:
          name: magento2.3-network-frontend
```

### SOLUTION

#### Example

Objective : to get `docker-compose start/stop` to work correctly with **multiple setups (aka projects/websites/tools)using the same docker-compose project**.

Suppose you have the following docker-compose files:

**Main file: ** `docker-compose.yml`:

```
   web_server:
       image: current_timezone/full-supervisord-web-server/php7.3:1.00
       container_name: web-server-apache2
       networks:
         - network_frontend
       build:
         context: "./all-services/"
         dockerfile: ./web-server/Dockerfile.webserver.apache2
         args:
       volumes:
         - website_data:/var/www/html
       ports:
         - "8080:8080"

   networks:
     network_frontend:
       driver: bridge
       ipam:
         driver: default
         config:
           - subnet: 172.100.0.0/16
       name: stage6-network-frontend
       driver_opts:
         # Custom name for host-side network : for instance on Ubuntu : ip addr | ifconfig
  com.docker.network.bridge.name: docker-custom # Seems limit of 15 characters only
```

**and then an override file**: `customfolder/magento2.override.yml`:

```
     web_server:
       container_name: web-server-apache2-magento2.3.5
       networks:
         - network_frontend
       build:
         args:
       volumes:
         - website_data:/var/www/html
       ports:
         - "8080:8080"

   networks:
     network_frontend:
       driver: bridge
       ipam:
         driver: default
         config:
           - subnet: 172.100.0.0/16
       driver_opts:
         # Custom name for host-side network : for instance on Ubuntu : ip addr | ifconfig
  com.docker.network.bridge.name: d-glo-femag2_35 # Seems limit of 15 characters only
       name: glo-magento2.3-network-frontend
```

### Do the following:

1. Copy the **full Docker project (Dockerfiles/ADDs/docker-compose.yml files etc) into a new seperate folder:**

   `/var/docker/project1`
   `/var/docker/project2`
2. Make sure that the `container_name` entries in your **override docker-compose.yml** are unique between the two projects.
3. In project `project1` run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f customfolder/magento2.override.yml up -d` && `docker-compose stop`, navigate to `project2` and do the same.

*Using `-p` flag as David Maze suggested does not work on its own, JSON files are still sourced as `./foldername` on `docker-compose start/stop`*

4. Since *networks are having similar issues on `start/stop`* , before you can correctly use your custom name defined in your override file, .... unfortunately you *need to update the main base `docker-compose.yml` to the overridden file!*

> Extended explanation: There is no way to call the correct custom network name from `docker-compose start`, so since docker-compose ignores the overridden files on `start`, you need to make sure to update the base file `docker-compose.yml` or `docker-compose.override.yml` has your custom network name.

In case you have not updated the names before using `up -d`, you will need to replace the content of each `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/config.v2.json`.

For example you could do this: *you have to stop docker first*

> ```
>   sudo service docker stop
>   find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -name "config.v2.json" -exec sed -i "s|wrong-network-name|overridden-network-name|g" '{}' \;
>   sudo service docker start
> ```

5. IF done correctly, you should have *unique container names, and each folder can be accessed separately correctly now without it breaking each other's containers: `docker-compose start`, `docker-compose stop`, `docker-compose ps`*

> **NOTE: You still need to navigate to the seperate folder to run those commands**